# Nested dictionaries: extracting paths to leaves

Tags: python

I have a Python nested dictionary as the following:

```
{'dist_river': 
  {'high': 
    {'wind_speed': 
      {'1': 
        {'population': 
          {'high': 
            {'school': 
              {'high':'T', 'medium':'T', 'low':'F'}
            }, 
            'medium': 
              {'land_cover': 
                {'Mix_garden': 
                  {'income_source': 
                    {'Plantation':'T', 'Agriculture':'F'}
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
    'low': 'F'
  }
}
```

How can I get subdictionaries from the nested dictionary ?.  For example, subdictionaries from dic:

```
results = [
    {'dist_river': 
     {'high': 
      {'wind_speed': 
       {'1': 
        {'population': 
         {'high': 
          {'school': 
           {'high': 'T', 'medium': 'T', 'low': 'F'}
          }}}}}}},

    {'dist_river': 
     {'high': 
      {'wind_speed': 
       {'1': 
        {'population': 
         {'medium': 
          {'land_cover': 
           {'Mix_garden': 
            {'income_source': 
             {'Plantation': 'T', 'Agriculture': 'F'}
            }}}}}}}}},

    {'dist_river': 
     {'low': 'F'}
    }
]

lengths(results) == 3
```

Thank you for your help

**community edit:** It appears that each resulting dictionary must have only one entry for each level of nesting. Put another way, each result contains the entire path to each leaf in the dictionary tree. – Tim Pietzcker 13 hours ago

Comment: What constitutes a subdictionary? How do you determine which parts should be in the subdictionary and which parts should be removed?

Comment: It appears that each resulting dictionary must have only one entry for each level of nesting. Put another way, each result contains the entire path to each leaf in the dictionary tree.

Comment: **voting to reopen**: Did no one read Tim Pietzcker's comment before voting to close? I have edited the question and title to be unambiguously clear.

Answer (score 7):

```
import collections

def isDict(d):
    return isinstance(d, collections.Mapping)

def isAtomOrFlat(d):
    return not isDict(d) or not any(isDict(v) for v in d.values())

def leafPaths(nestedDicts, noDeeper=isAtomOrFlat):
    """
        For each leaf in NESTEDDICTS, this yields a 
        dictionary consisting of only the entries between the root
        and the leaf.
    """
    for key,value in nestedDicts.items():
        if noDeeper(value):
            yield {key: value}
        else:
            for subpath in leafPaths(value):
                yield {key: subpath}
```

Demo:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(list( leafPaths(dic) ))
[{'dist_river': {'high': {'wind_speed': {'1': {'population': {'high': {'school': {'high': 'T',
                                                                                  'low': 'F',
                                                                                  'medium': 'T'}}}}}}}},
 {'dist_river': {'high': {'wind_speed': {'1': {'population': {'medium': {'land_cover': {'Mix_garden': {'income_source': {'Agriculture': 'F',
                                                                                                                         'Plantation': 'T'}}}}}}}}}},
 {'dist_river': {'low': 'F'}}]
```

---

**sidenote 1**: However unless this format was warranted for some reason I personally feel it would be better to yield nodes in the manner of tuples, e.g. something like:

```
...noDeeper=lambda x:not isDict(x)...
...yield tuple(value)
...yield (key,)+subpath

[('dist_river', 'high', 'wind_speed', '1', 'population', 'high', 'school', 'high', 'T'),
 ('dist_river', 'high', 'wind_speed', '1', 'population', 'high', 'school', 'medium', 'T'),
 ('dist_river', 'high', 'wind_speed', '1', 'population', 'high', 'school', 'low', 'F'),
 ('dist_river', 'high', 'wind_speed', '1', 'population', 'medium', 'land_cover', 'Mix_garden', 'income_source', 'Plantation', 'T'),
 ('dist_river', 'high', 'wind_speed', '1', 'population', 'medium', 'land_cover', 'Mix_garden', 'income_source', 'Agriculture', 'F'),
 ('dist_river', 'low', 'F')]
```

(Extracted easily from the "straightforward" answer, which happens to be thg435's answer.)

---

**sidenote 2:** Do note that the naive implementation is not what the OP is looking for. The naive implementation would have `noDeeper=lambda x:not isDict(x)`, with the result of:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(list( leafPaths(dic) ))
[{'dist_river': {'high': {'wind_speed': {'1': {'population': {'high': {'school': {'high': 'T'}}}}}}}},
 {'dist_river': {'high': {'wind_speed': {'1': {'population': {'high': {'school': {'medium': 'T'}}}}}}}},
 {'dist_river': {'high': {'wind_speed': {'1': {'population': {'high': {'school': {'low': 'F'}}}}}}}},
 {'dist_river': {'high': {'wind_speed': {'1': {'population': {'medium': {'land_cover': {'Mix_garden': {'income_source': {'Plantation': 'T'}}}}}}}}}},
 {'dist_river': {'high': {'wind_speed': {'1': {'population': {'medium': {'land_cover': {'Mix_garden': {'income_source': {'Agriculture': 'F'}}}}}}}}}},
 {'dist_river': {'low': 'F'}}]
```

---

Edit: this is an inefficient algorithm. Each leaf L is re-yielded `depth(L)` times. More efficient would be to chain generators maybe with a custom data structure, or simulate the stack manually.

Comment: Excellent. I wish I could upvote this more than once.

Comment: Your answer is great, I don't understand why so many guys choose to close question only when they didn't understand the problem, stackoverflow is running down recently.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
def enum_paths(p):
    if not hasattr(p, 'items'):
        yield p
    else:
        for k, v in p.items():
            for x in enum_paths(v):
                yield {k: x}


for x in enum_paths(dic):
    print x
```

Answer (score 0):

It's done exactly the same way as 'getting' any other *value* from a dictionary.

```
print dic1['dist_river']['high']
```

and so on.

EDIT:

In case I misunderstood the question and it's really about getting a list of all dicts at once, here's an example for the case there's only one key in each of them:

```
def get_nested_dicts(d):
    dicts = []
    probe = d
    while type(probe) == dict:
        dicts.append(probe)
        probe = probe.values()[0]
    return dicts
```

Comment: It's a lot more complicated than that. You need a recursive approach to "walk down" the tree of dictionaries.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question.